# Não consigo instalar o numpy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Ao chamar uma aplicação Python aparece escrito

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\benev\OneDrive\programaþÒo\ML\classificacao.py", line 15, in
>   
>   from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomiaNB   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 57, in
>   
>   from .base import clone   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 8, in 
>   import numpy as np ImportError: No module named numpy

e não estou conseguindo instalar o NumPy. Como faço?

Comment: E como tentou instalá-lo?

Comment: Então procurei no chocolatey.org/packages e depois baixei um programa para instalar o numpy, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Tente rodar na linha de comando: `pip install numpy`

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!